# Responsive images when image width is not proportional to viewport width?

Tags: javascript, css, image, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design

I am using Twitter Bootstrap's [responsive grid](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/scaffolding.html), and I would like to include some images as part of my page, as follows:

```
<div class="row">
<div class="span3"><img src="img1.png" /></div>
<div class="span3"><img src="img2.png" /></div>
<div class="span3"><img src="img3.png" /></div>
<div class="span3"><img src="img4.png" /></div>
</div>
```

However, it is hard to make the images responsive, because with Bootstrap image width is not related directly to viewport width, which rules out e.g. the [Filament](https://github.com/filamentgroup/Responsive-Images) approach.

In the example above, on a 1080-pixel-wide screen the images stack so each div takes up less than 25% of the viewport width, and each image only needs to be ~250px wide. However, on an 750-pixel-wide screen, the divs stack vertically to take up 100% of the viewport width, so each image needs to be ~750px wide.

I was thinking I could do something like:

- By default, load a spacer.gif: `<img src="spacer.gif" />`
- On page load, check the width of the image, and load the appropriate size

But then I realised that won't work for non-JavaScript users. I could load a small image by default, but then non-JS users get a bad experience on large screens, and some users will also have to load both the small and large images.

Any recommendations?

Comment: Try using `row-fluid` instead.

Answer (score 1):

If your primary concern is not loading unnecessarily large images on mobile devices, and you're looking for a non-JS option, perhaps you might find something like [Sencha.io Src](http://docs.sencha.io/0.3.3/index.html#!/guide/src) useful.  Basically, you route all your images through Sencha:

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="span3"><img src="http://src.sencho.io/http://yourimageserver.com/img1.png" /></div>
  <div class="span3"><img src="http://src.sencho.io/http://yourimageserver.com/img2.png" /></div>
  <div class="span3"><img src="http://src.sencho.io/http://yourimageserver.com/img3.png" /></div>
  <div class="span3"><img src="http://src.sencho.io/http://yourimageserver.com/img4.png" /></div>
</div>
```

The Sencha server then checks the user-agent in the HTTP Request Header, and then serves a predetermined size based on the specs they have about the browser.

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to solve this client-side, you can use [PictureFill](https://github.com/scottjehl/picturefill)

Basically, it implements a similar solution to the proposed  [element in W3C](http://www.w3.org/TR/html-picture-element/). You would insert the following into your markup (from the example on the PictureFill site):

```
<div data-picture data-alt="A giant stone face at The Bayon temple in Angkor Thom, Cambodia">
    <div data-src="small.jpg"></div>
    <div data-src="medium.jpg"     data-media="(min-width: 400px)"></div>
    <div data-src="large.jpg"      data-media="(min-width: 800px)"></div>
    <div data-src="extralarge.jpg" data-media="(min-width: 1000px)"></div>

    <!-- Fallback content for non-JS browsers. Same img src as the initial, unqualified source element. -->
    <noscript>
        <img src="external/imgs/small.jpg" alt="A giant stone face at The Bayon temple in Angkor Thom, Cambodia">
    </noscript>
</div>
```

The `<noscript>` avoids the browser having to download a spacer.gif and also serves as a fallback where there is no JS available; the user just gets the small.jpg which would be suitable for older mobiles with javascript disabled.

The `(min-width: ...)` media queries allow you to choose breakpoints based on device sizes, you can also use `(min-device-pixel-ratio: 2.0)` for HD devices like Retina displays.

For your purposes, you could set something like:

```
 <div data-src="image_250x250.jpg"     data-media="(min-width: 1080px)"></div>
 <div data-src="image_750x750.jpg"     data-media="(min-width: 750px)"></div>
```

And use media queries in your css to make sure the 250x250 images stack.

Hope that helps!